# Updating object in Realm with Nil not working

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having issues with updating an object in Realm. I have an object (*UserData*) with a property (*imageUrl*) which stores the user url image.

If I remove the image from other device and I try to update refresh user information from the current device, I receive a JSON with that field as I expect, with `nil` value. But after save it with Realm and recover it again, the value of that field is the value before deleting the image remotely.

The code which persists it is:

```
func saveUserData(_ user:UserData){
    do{
        try realm.write(){
            realm.create(UserData.self, value: user, update: true)
        }
    }catch{
    }
}
```

The variable `user`is correct so there is any problem mapping it from the *JSON*.

I'm using *RxRealm*, I observe UserData changes and it works perfectly when a field has changed to a value different to `nil`.

Comment: Hmm, to clarify, does your object have a valid primary key when you do this? If not, it may just be creating a new copy of the object instead.

Comment: Yes, my primary key is a dynamic string named `url`. And the method 
which indicates that the primary key is that is:
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "url"
    }

Comment: Hmm, okay. That should be fine then. Have you tried opening your Realm file in the Realm Browser? That should let you confirm that the property was  properly set to `nil` or not.

Comment: Related to this bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5000